# Adding instances with a one-to-many connection

Tags: django, django-models

I have objects:

```
class Subscribe(models.Model):
   id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   name=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=False);
   owner=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='owner', null=False, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)# владелец подписки
   subscription = models.ManyToManyField(User,null=True,related_name='subscription') #те, на кого он пдписалса
```

In this code I want to connect the objects of the user with the object article like in admin:

[image]

```
@login_required(login_url="/account/login")
def sunscribe(request,id):
    user=User.objects.get(pk=id) #article author
    try:
        sunscribe1=Subscribe.objects.get(owner=request.user)
    except Subscribe.DoesNotExist:
        sunscribe1 = Subscribe();
```

But I have error:
"" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

But I have field id!

Comment: inside except block, `sunscribe1 = Subscribe.objects.create(name='something', owner=request.user)`